# One to One Relationship and compound forms (Symfony 3.4)

Tags: php, symfony

I have 2 entities, Exercise and Product, they have a One to One relationship (the owning side is Product), and I have an ExerciseFormType and a ProductFormType.

What I want I to be able to create an exercise, and the product associated with it at the same time.

My idea was to add the the builder of exerciseFormType, 'product' and its type would be a ProductFormType. The problem is that the product needs the exercise_id, and the exercise isn't persisted yet so it doesn't have one. Here's what I have so far (it works only for creating a product when the exercise exists).

```
    class ExerciseType extends AbstractType {

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
            $builder->add('name')
                    ->add('content')
                    ->add('language')
                    ->add('level')
                    ->add('skillsRequired')
                    ->add('skillsTargetted')
                    ->add('tags')
                    ->add('product', ProductType::class, array(
                        'required' => false,
                        'exercise'=> $builder->getData()
                        )
                    );
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver){
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => 'SchoolBundle\Entity\Exercise'
            ));
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function getBlockPrefix(){
            return 'schoolbundle_exercise';
        }

class ProductType extends AbstractType {
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){

        $builder->add('visibility')->add('price', MoneyType::class);

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $product = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();

            $field = (!$product || null === $product->getId()) ? 'publicationDate' : 'updateDate';
            $form->add($field, DateTimeType::class, array('data' => new \DateTime()));

        });

        $data = array(
            'data' => $options['exercise'],
            'class' => Exercise::class,
            'choice_label' => 'getName'
        );

        $builder->add('exercise', EntityType::class, $data);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver){
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'MarketBundle\Entity\Product'
        ));

        $resolver->setRequired(array(
            'exercise'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix(){
        return 'marketbundle_product';
    }


}
```

In exercise I have that

```
  <?php
    /**
     * exercise
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="exercise")
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SchoolBundle\Repository\ExerciseRepository")
     */
    class Exercise {
        /**
         * @var int
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @var string
         * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $name;

        /**
         * @var string
         * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $content;

        /**
         * @var string
         * @ORM\Column(name="language", type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $language;

        /**
         * @var int
         * @ORM\Column(name="level", type="integer")
         */
        private $level;

        /**
         * @var string
         * @ORM\Column(name="skills_required", type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $skillsRequired;

        /**
         * @var string
         * @ORM\Column(name="skills_targetted", type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $skillsTargetted;

        /**
         * @var string
         * @ORM\Column(name="tags", type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $tags;

        /**
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Session", mappedBy="exercise")
         */
        private $sessions;

        /**
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ExerciseIO", mappedBy="exercise")
         */
        private $exerciseIOs;

        /**
         * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="MarketBundle\Entity\Product", mappedBy="exercise", cascade={"persist"}))
         */
        private $product;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Professor", inversedBy="createdExercises")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="creator_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
         */
        private $creator;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Professor", mappedBy="boughtExercises")
         */
        private $owners;

        public function __construct(){
            $this->sessions = new ArrayCollection();
            $this->exerciseIOs = new ArrayCollection();
            $this->owners = new ArrayCollection();
        }

        /**
         * Get creator
         * @return Professor
         */
        public function getCreator(){
            return $this->creator;
        }

        /**
         * Set creator
         * @param Professor $creator
         * @return Exercise
         */
        public function setCreator($creator){
            $this->creator = $creator;
            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get owner
         * @return ArrayCollection
         */
        public function getOwners(){
            return $this->owners;
        }

        /**
         * Get product
         * @return Product
         */
        public function getProduct(){
            return $this->product;
        }


        /**
         * @param Product $product
         * @return Exercise
         */
        public function setProduct($product){
            $this->product = $product;
            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get exerciseIOs
         * @return ArrayCollection
         */
        public function getExerciseIOs(){
            return $this->exerciseIOs;
        }

        /**
         * Get sessions
         * @return ArrayCollection
         */
        public function getSessions(){
            return $this->sessions;
        }

        /**
         * Get id
         * @return int
         */
        public function getId(){
            return $this->id;
        }

        /**
         * Set name
         * @param string $name
         * @return Exercise
         */
        public function setName($name){
            $this->name = $name;
            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get name
         * @return string
         */
        public function getName(){
            return $this->name;
        }

        /**
         * Set content
         * @param string $content
         * @return Exercise
         */
        public function setContent($content){
            $this->content = $content;
            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get content
         * @return string
         */
        public function getContent(){
            return $this->content;
        }

        /**
         * Set language
         * @param string $language
         * @return Exercise
         */
        public function setLanguage($language){
            $this->language = $language;
            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get language
         * @return string
         */
        public function getLanguage(){
            return $this->language;
        }

        /**
         * Set level
         * @param string $level
         * @return Exercise
         */
        public function setLevel($level){
            $this->level = $level;
            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get level
         * @return string
         */
        public function getLevel(){
            return $this->level;
        }

        /**
         * Set skillsRequired
         * @param string $skillsRequired
         * @return Exercise
         */
        public function setSkillsRequired($skillsRequired){
            $this->skillsRequired = $skillsRequired;
            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get skillsRequired
         * @return string
         */
        public function getSkillsRequired(){
            return $this->skillsRequired;
        }

        /**
         * Set skillsTargetted
         * @param string $skillsTargetted
         * @return Exercise
         */
        public function setSkillsTargetted($skillsTargetted){
            $this->skillsTargetted = $skillsTargetted;
            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get skillsTargetted
         * @return string
         */
        public function getSkillsTargetted(){
            return $this->skillsTargetted;
        }

        /**
         * Set tags
         * @param string $tags
         * @return Exercise
         */
        public function setTags($tags){
            $this->tags = $tags;
            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get tags
         * @return string
         */
        public function getTags(){
            return $this->tags;
        }
    }
```

And in Product

```
/**
 * Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="\MarketBundle\Repository\ProductRepository")
 */
class Product {

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var bool
     * @ORM\Column(name="visibility", type="boolean")
     */
    private $visibility;

    /**
     * @var float
     * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="float")
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(name="publication_date", type="datetimetz")
     */
    private $publicationDate;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(name="update_date", type="datetimetz", nullable=true)
     */
    private $updateDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductComment", mappedBy="product")
     */
    private $productComments;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\SchoolBundle\Entity\Exercise", inversedBy="product")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="exercise_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $exercise;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->productComments = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get exercise
     * @return Exercise
     */
    public function getExercise(){
        return $this->exercise;
    }

    /**
     * Set exercise
     * @param Exercise $exercise
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setExercise($exercise){
        $this->exercise = $exercise;
        return $this;
    }



    /**
     * Get productComments
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getProductComments(){
        return $this->productComments;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set visibility
     * @param boolean $visibility
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setVisibility($visibility){
        $this->visibility = $visibility;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get visibility
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getVisibility(){
        return $this->visibility;
    }

    /**
     * Set price
     * @param float $price
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setPrice($price){
        $this->price = $price;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get price
     * @return float
     */
    public function getPrice(){
        return $this->price;
    }

    /**
     * Set publicationDate
     * @param \DateTime $publicationDate
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setPublicationDate($publicationDate){
        $this->publicationDate = $publicationDate;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get publicationDate
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getPublicationDate(){
        return $this->publicationDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set updateDate
     * @param \DateTime $updateDate
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setUpdateDate($updateDate){
        $this->updateDate = $updateDate;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updateDate
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUpdateDate(){
        return $this->updateDate;
    }
}
```

I've said it works for an existing exercise (and no product).
When I try to create both at the same time I get

Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist them in the entity manager?

It's probably from the $builder->getData(), because in that case I only passed to the form a "new Exercice()". Here's the controller action

```
public function newAction(Request $request){

        $exercise = new Exercise();
        $form = $this->createForm(ExerciseType::class, $exercise);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $exercise->setCreator($this->getUser());
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($exercise);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('exercise_show', array('id' => $exercise->getId()));
        }
```

(Also this is another question but when I disable a formType, it is rendered, and the value appears but it's not submitted. I would actually prefer a hiddenFormType but I need the formatting of the DateTimeFormType)

Comment: Sorry for that but you should avoid one to one relaitionships, thought about inheritance?

Comment: Hmhm, well the idea is that I have an exercise that can be put on a marketplace or not. I figured, you can add it or remove it by creating or deleting the associated product. If it were inheritance, wouldn't I have to change the whole object ?

Comment: Can you provide the entity properties and its annotations? Have you tried `->add('product', new ProductType());` instead `->add('product', ProductType::class, array(/*...*/));`? I have done this kind of feature, but with Symfony2.8!

Comment: new ProductType() gives me : Expected argument of type "string", "MarketBundle\Form\Type\ProductType" given

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is the solution I've made once with Symfony2.8, I hope it can helps you.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="picture")
 */
class Picture
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Host",
     *     inversedBy="pictureId"
     * )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="avatar_host_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $avatarHostId;

}
```

---

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="host")
 */
class Host
{

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Picture",
     *     mappedBy="avatarHostId", cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"}
     * )
     */
    private $pictureId;
}
```

---

```
class HostType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('pictureId', PictureFileType::class); 
    }
}
```

---

```
class PictureFileType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('assetFile', FileType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Picture File',
                'required' => false,
                'validation_groups' => array('creation')
            ));
    }
}
```

Comment: new ProductType() gives me : Expected argument of type "string", "MarketBundle\Form\Type\ProductType" given

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend moving away from using integers as IDs. There are some issues around them, including that you can't really generate one at will in this kind of scenario. I would recommend [`Uuid`s along with ramsey/uuid](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid), which also has a [Doctrine mapping](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid-doctrine).

When you've got a situation where you need an ID before it's been persisted and the `Uuid` generated, generate the `Uuid` yourself. For instance, in a contrived example

```
class Order
{
    /**
     * @var UuidInterface
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="uuid")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class=UuidGenerator::class)
     */
    private $id;

    ...

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param UuidInterface $id
     */
    public function __construct(?UuidInterface $id = null)
    {
        $this->id = $id ?? Uuid::uuid4();
    }

    ...
}

class OrderController
{
    ...

    public function orderProductAction(): JsonResponse
    {
        ...

        // We need this ahead of time, because
        // maybe this is Async and we need to
        // return the order id. This happens a
        // lot with commands.
        $generatedId = Uuid::uuid4();

        // Here it's going to use the given ID,
        // if not given, the Order class will
        // generate it.
        $order = new Order($generatedId, ...);

        // Stuff happens, persisted... maybe we
        // don't have the persisted Order object...

        return $this->json([
            'order' => [
                'id' => $generatedId->toString(),
            ],
        ]);
    }

    ...
}
```

The meat of it is providing the generated `Uuid` in the constructor (which alternately generates it if `null`). Do *not* add a setter. Here's a more involved example:

```
public function createAction(Request $request): JsonResponse
{
    $request_data = \json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
    $tenant_data = $request_data['data'];

    // Pre-generate our Uuid for the Tenant.
    $generated_id = Uuid::uuid4();

    /** @var CreateTenant $create_tenant_cmd */
    $create_tenant_cmd = new CreateTenant($generated_id);

    $create_tenant_cmd->setName($tenant_data['name']);
    $create_tenant_cmd->setDomainName($tenant_data['domain_name']);
    $create_tenant_cmd->setOwnerUsername($tenant_data['owner_username']);
    $create_tenant_cmd->setOwnerPassword($tenant_data['owner_password']);
    $create_tenant_cmd->setOwnerFirstName($tenant_data['owner_first_name']);
    $create_tenant_cmd->setOwnerLastName($tenant_data['owner_last_name']);
    $create_tenant_cmd->setOwnerEmail($tenant_data['owner_email']);

    if (!$this->isGranted('perform', $create_tenant_cmd)) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('Access denied to create tenant.');
    }

    // Here, we should expect NO side-effects, the command
    // can't return anything. So no Tenant object with 
    // generated Uuid...
    $this->get('command_bus')->handle($create_tenant_cmd);

    /* @var Serializer $serializer */
    $serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');
    $serializer_context = SerializationContext::create()->setGroups([
        'tenant_meta',
    ]);

    $tenant = $this->get('app.repository.tenant')->find($generated_id);

    return $this->json(\json_decode($serializer->serialize(
        $tenant,
        'json',
        $serializer_context
    )));
}
```

That's the ID question; the second part of your question is now easily resolved, that being giving the `Uuid` to the `FormType` instead:

```
$form = $this->createForm(OrderProductType::class, $product, [
    'product' => $product,
    'generatedId' => $generatedId,
]);

class OrderProductType extends AbstractType implements DataMapperInterface
{
    /** @var UuidInterface */
    protected $generatedId;

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $this->generatedId = $options['generatedId'];
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver
            ->setDefaults([
                'data_class' => OrderProduct::class,
            ])
            ->setRequired(['generatedId'])
        ;
    }

    public function mapFormsToData($forms, &$data)
    {
        $forms = iterator_to_array($forms);

        $data = new OrderProduct($this->generatedId);

        ...
    }

}
```

Of course, if you need it as a field, use it with the field type of your choice instead of storing it as a variable, and then get it from that field:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('product_id', HiddenType::class, [
            'product_id' => $options['generatedId']->toString(),
        ])
        ...
    ;
}

public function mapFormsToData($forms, &$data)
{
    $forms = iterator_to_array($forms);

    // Note use of Uuid::fromString().
    $data = new OrderProduct(Uuid::fromString(
        $forms['productId']->getData()
    ));

    ...
}
```

This is one of the downsides of not delegating the *process* of interaction to a delegate object like a command, instead of generating an entity; you're stuck constructing your object before you need it, in whole, or perverting the design to make it fit. It also makes working with assertions harder as well (you only get one set, the entity's).

Comment: I see, thanks for the answer, My problem doesn't seem like an uncommon one, so I thought symfony supported it and I just didn't find the right documentation, but if there really is no way to do it, i'm going to consider your solution

Comment: One-to-one would make sense here if the `Exercise` was something like `ExerciseConfiguration`, and thus each `Product` represents the purchase "configuration" of an a la carte `Exercise` which was really a module on X, Y and Z. For instance, buying a certification with different options.